# Como manipular a DOM de um arquivo XHTML com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml

Arquivo JS:

```
//Variáveis Globais - HTML
var campoMatricula = document.querySelector(".matriculaInput");
var campoNome = document.querySelector(".nomeInput");
var campoAno = document.querySelector(".anoInput");
var confirmaBtn = document.querySelector(".confirmaBtn");
var cancelaBtn = document.querySelector(".cancelaBtn");

//Funções
function validaMatricula(e){
    var tecla = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var regex = /[0-9]/;
    if(! (tecla.match(regex)) || campoMatricula.value.length >= 14){
        return false;
    }
}


function validaAno(e){
    var tecla = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var regex = /[0-9]/;
    if(! (tecla.match(regex)) || campoAno.value.length >= 4){
        return false;
    }
}

function validaNome(e) {
    var tecla = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var regex = /[a-zA-Z ]/;
    if(! (tecla.match(regex)) || campoNome.value.length >= 100){
        return false;
    }
}

function verificaDadosVazio(event) {
    campoNome.value = campoNome.value.trim(); // Remove espaços desnecessários
    if (campoMatricula.value == "") {
        alert("Preencha a matrícula!");
    }
    else if(campoNome.value == "" ){
        alert("Preencha o nome!");
    }
    else if(campoAno.value == ""){
        alert("Preencha o ano!");
    }
}

//Rotina Principal
campoAno.onkeypress = validaAno;
campoMatricula.onkeypress = validaMatricula;
campoNome.onkeypress = validaNome;
confirmaBtn.addEventListener("click", verificaDadosVazios);
```

O meu arquivo xhtml é esse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo_formulario.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formulario.js"/>

    <title>Projeto JSF</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="cabecalho">Univesidade Equipe Orbitais</h1>
        <div class="main">
            <h2 class="subtitulo">Formulário para Cadastro de Novo Aluno</h2>
            <div class="conteudoPrincipal">

                <h:link outcome="#{alunoMBean.chamaIndex()}">
                    <h:graphicImage class="imagemAcao" value="imagens/home.png" />
                </h:link>
                <p class="chamadaAcao">Página Inicial</p>

                <h:form class="formulario">
                    <h:outputLabel class="matriculaLabel" value="Matricula: "/>
                    <h:inputText class="matriculaInput" value="#{alunoMBean.aluno.matricula}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputLabel class="nomeLabel" value="Nome: "/>  
                    <h:inputText class="nomeInput" value="#{alunoMBean.aluno.pessoa.name}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputLabel class="anoLabel" value="Ano de Entrada: "/>
                    <h:inputText class="anoInput" value="#{alunoMBean.aluno.anoDeEntrada}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:commandButton class="confirmaBtn" value="Confirmar" action="#{alunoMBean.save}"/>
                    <h:commandButton class="cancelaBtn" value="Cancelar"/>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Quando abro o browser e clico em exibir código fonte, tenho esse código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo_formulario.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/formulario.js"></script>

    <title>Projeto JSF</title></head><body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="cabecalho">Univesidade Equipe Orbitais</h1>
        <div class="main">
            <h2 class="subtitulo">Formulário para Cadastro de Novo Aluno</h2>
            <div class="conteudoPrincipal"><a href="/teste/index.xhtml"><img src="imagens/home.png" class="imagemAcao" /></a>
                <p class="chamadaAcao">Página Inicial</p>
<form id="j_idt9" name="j_idt9" method="post" action="/teste/formulario.xhtml" class="formulario" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt9" value="j_idt9" />
<label class="matriculaLabel">Matricula: </label><input type="text" name="j_idt9:j_idt11" class="matriculaInput" />
                    <br /><label class="nomeLabel">Nome: </label><input type="text" name="j_idt9:j_idt14" class="nomeInput" />
                    <br /><label class="anoLabel">Ano de Entrada: </label><input type="text" name="j_idt9:j_idt17" class="anoInput" />
                    <br /><input type="submit" name="j_idt9:j_idt19" value="Confirmar" class="confirmaBtn" /><input type="submit" name="j_idt9:j_idt20" value="Cancelar" class="cancelaBtn" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-8600842127533715592:846504525323161492" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></body>
</html>
```

Opa,
Estou tentando criar uma váriavel em javascript que represente um elemento da página, o arquivo da página é xhtml, mas quando eu entro no console do browser ele "converte" para html(não sei dizer pq kk).

Mas Enfim, O problema é que o javascript não acha nenhum desses elementos e eles acabam ficando **null**.

OBS: já tentei colocar as tags html e xhtml antes, tipo assim:

> input.matriculaInput

e

> inputText.matriculaInput

Como posso fazer pra que o javascript possa reconhecer as tags e armazena-las nas variáveis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que atribuir valor nessas "variáveis globais" dentro das funções que as usam, senão serão sempre vazias, pois os valores delas estão sendo atribuídos na abertura da página e não nas funções.

Por exemplo, a variável...

```
var campoNome = document.querySelector(".nomeInput");
```

...estará vazia no carregamento da página, pois o campo `.nomeInput` não tem nada. Ao utilizar essa variável na função `validaNome`, ela continuará vazia, pois você não fez nenhuma alteração na variável que já foi declarada, e com isso o código `campoNome.value.length` será sempre `0`.

Então, dentro da função que irá usá-la, tem que pegar o valor atualizado do input usando outra variável:

```
function validaNome(e) {
    var campoNomeVal = campoNome.value; // pega o valor atual do input
    var tecla = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var regex = /[a-zA-Z ]/;
    if(! (tecla.match(regex)) || campoNomeVal.length >= 100){
        return false;
    }
}
```

E o mesmo com as outras variáveis, uma em cada função onde são usadas.

Comment: Hummm, faz muito sentido isso ae... É pq eu pensava que esse querySelector iria retorna o conjunto da tag sabe?  Vou tentar fazer assim

Comment: Percebi uma coisa, se eu não colocar a variável global e declara-la dentro da função como que eu vou chamar a função sob o onkeypress? estava fazendo assim: campoAno.onkeypress = validaAno;     mas se eu declarar na função não vai ter como

Comment: O botão não tem problema porque ele não é alterado, mas no caso dos inputs sim.

Comment: Então nem rola só declarar a global, e chamar o queryselector em cada função tbm, pq seu n tenho os campos definidos antes de chamar o onkeypress ele n vai ter como saber aonde eu to apertando

Comment: Tem razão. Eu não percebi que vc está usando eventos nos inputs. Alterei a resposta. Dá uma olhada agora.

Comment: Man, eu acho que eu me expressei mal na pergunta... o problema não é value das variaveis estar null, o problema é que ela não reconhece as tags quando carrega a página tlgd, tipo se eu entrar nesse arquivo vai da erro no  browser, mas se eu vor no console e digitar a mesma linha de código que define as variaveis ela funciona tranquilo e retorna a tag encontrada, era isso que eu tava querendo dizer na pergunta, mas acho que ficou meio confuso ksjdk

Comment: Deve ser porque vc está carregando o .js antes do DOM. Tenta colocando todo o código JS dentro desse evento: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ COLOCA TUDO AQUI DENTRO });`

Comment: Mano, deu certo !!! Tea mo boe!! não sabia desse evento man, muito top